# PHP MySQL doesn't perform update using substring

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, substring

I am facing an issue with PHP which doesn't perform one query in my script.
The SQL query works well in my MYSQL console but nothing is happening. Year column stays NULL:

```
$UpdateYear='UPDATE `pat` SET `Year` = SUBSTRING(`Prepa`,7,4)';
mysqli_query($connWarehouse,$UpdateYear) or   die(mysqli_error($connWarehouse));
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here the full script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db="datawarehouse";

// Create connection
$connWarehouse = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($connWarehouse->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connWarehouse->connect_error);
}
$UpdateYear='UPDATE `pat` SET `Year` = SUBSTRING(`Prepa`,7,4)';
    mysqli_query($connWarehouse,$UpdateYear) or   die(mysqli_error($connWarehouse));

mysqli_close($connWarehouse));
?>
```

Comment: What is in the DB field `Prepa`? What type of field is `Year`?

Comment: Field Prepa is a varchar(10) and Year is defined as YEAR.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `SUBSTRING(Prepa,7,4)` by something like `"1998"` ?

Comment: What value is **in** Prepa?

Comment: Prepa is defined as varchar(10) and it contains values like 17/06/2018

Comment: Does it always set `Year` to `null`? Is it possible that the values in the field are not formatted the way you expect?

Comment: In theory MySQL should convert any invalid year values with `0000` and not `NULL`. So this is contradictory with the issue you described, there's obviously something wrong or missing in your description of the problem

Comment: The query UPDATE `pat` SET `Year` = SUBSTRING(`Prepa`,7,4) works well in MySQL but not in PHP script which I don't understand why. The Column `Year` stays NULL when it is performed by PHP

Comment: can you add result of `show create table pat` to your post.

Comment: Here's the result of show create table pat: CREATE TABLE `pat` (
  `Pat` varchar(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DatePrepa` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Which is weird, if i execute $UpdateYear='UPDATE `pat` SET `Year` = SUBSTRING(`Prepa`,7,4)';
    mysqli_query($connWarehouse,$UpdateYear) or   die(mysqli_error($connWarehouse)); alone it works but, if I try:$AddYear='ALTER TABLE `patnexlab` ADD COLUMN `Year` YEAR';
mysqli_query($connWarehouse,$AddYear) or die(mysqli_error($connWarehouse)); $UpdateYear='UPDATE `pat` SET `Year` = SUBSTRING(`Prepa`,7,4)';
    mysqli_query($connWarehouse,$UpdateYear) or   die(mysqli_error($connWarehouse)); it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve. I don't know if it is a correct way to do it. I have to open a new connection to the database in order to perform.

**alter.php:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db="datawarehouse";

// Create connection
$connWarehouse = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($connWarehouse->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connWarehouse->connect_error);
}
$AddYear='ALTER TABLE `pat` ADD COLUMN `Year` YEAR;';
mysqli_query($connWarehouse,$AddYear) or die(mysqli_error($connWarehouse));

mysqli_close($connWarehouse));
include 'uppat.php';
?>
```

**uppat.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'config-datawarehouse.php';

$UpdateYear='UPDATE `pat` SET `Year` = SUBSTRING(`DatePrepa`,7,4)';

mysqli_query($conn,$UpdateYear) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

On that way it performed the update query.